# Should I Always Fully Qualify Column Names In SQL?

Tags: sql, coding-style

Out of interest when working with SQL statements should I always use the fully qualifed column name (tablename.columnname) even if only working with one table e.g.

```
SELECT table.column1, table.column2 FROM table
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's better if you do - it doesn't add any complexity, and it can prevent errors in the future.

But in a well-defined system, you shouldn't *have* to - it's like namespaces in programming languages.  The ideal is not to have conflicts, but it can clutter the code with the superfluous use of explicit names.

-Adam

Answer (score 5):

I generally follow these rules:

When using a single table, it is not necessary to use the table name prefix:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1
```

For multiple tables, use the full table name.  Aliases can be confusing, especially when doing multiple joins:

```
SELECT table1.col1, table2.col2 FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 on 
            table1.id = table2.id
```

I see many developers using table aliases, but particularly in large projects with multiple developers, these can become cryptic.  A few extra keystrokes can provide a lot more clarity in the code.

If may, however, become necessary to use a column alias when columns have the same name.  In that case:

```
    SELECT table1.col1, table2.col1 as table2_col1 FROM table1 
            INNER JOIN table2 on 
            table1.id = table2.id
```

Comment: and when you're joining the same table more than once?

Comment: Joe - good point.  You would definitely need to alias the tabled in that case.

Comment: I'd say that for longer table names (and/or ones you don't necessarily own) aliases can end up being more useful than the tablenames themselves.  I'm looking at YOU, HP Service Desk schema.

Answer (score 2):

I would put this as personal preference. It would only make a difference if you started joining tables which contain duplicate column names.

Also, rather than write out the table name in full, use an alias:

SELECT t.column1, t.column2 FROM table as t

Comment: I always use aliases when there's more than one table.  It makes it easier for me to write, and no one has complained about not being able to read it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only selecting from one table I do not see the overall usefulness. If you are selecting from multiple tables, qualifying the column names would certainly make it easier to read for any other developer who may not be familiar with your database schema.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only querying one table - I'd say no. It's more readable that way.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't solve problems you don't have yet.**  (At least that's what my team lead is always telling me.)  I'm sure the monkey who someday has to add a JOIN to your statement can figure it out.

Comment: So true.  Never make program changes outside the ones in your task. +1 back to 0.  Now if this is a new project then do what your lead says not what stackoverflow says.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a good idea to always use the fully qualified column name. Use an alias if the table name is too long. It also prepares your queries for futures additions of e.g. joins.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is nice to use qualified name, it adds readability to your code. It does not make much sense to use it for single table but for multiple tables it is must. if table names are too big then it is recommended to use alias, alias should preferably be derived from table name.

```
SELECT Dep.Name,Emp.Name
FROM Department DEP INNER JOIN Employee Emp
ON Dep.departmentid=Emp.DepartmentID
```

Answer (score 0):

Even the most well defined systems are subject to change. A new field could quite easily be introduced to a table causing ambiguity in an existing query.

Fully qualifying them protects you from this scenario.

Answer (score -1):

I prefer to use a table alias when more than 1 table is in play.

Comment: If your tables are named properly, why do you need a table alias?

Comment: Because table names can be long.

Comment: because i didn't name them :)

Comment: And short aliases are more prone to ambiguity.

Comment: If your table names are clear and concise, using a table alias is only degrading the readability of your queries.

Comment: I use the table alias to make it clear and concise and faster to type. The table names are long and the view names are even longer.

Answer (score -1):

**No.**

You should always **alias** the tables, and you should always qualify your column names with the table **aliases**.

```
select
    p.FirstName,
    p.LastName,
    p.SSN
from Person p
where p.ID = 345
```