# SQL-92 Selecting with the dot operator

Tags: sql, join, tags, ansi-sql

Before it is marked as a duplicate, I am not asking If I have to specify it fully, I am why it does not matter if it is specified. Hope that clears that up. Now to the question.

I'm new to SQL so I'm not sure if there is some technical term for this.

Say I have a database with tables: Orders and Customers.

Orders has categories: OrderID, CustomerID, and OrderDate

Customers has categories: CustomerID, CustomerName, ContactName, and Country

I then have a SQL Query:

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID;
```

So I am selecting `Orders.OrderID`, `Customers.CustomerName`, and `Orders.OrderDate` `FROM` `Orders` table. If it is from the Orders table, why specify `Orders.` before the `OrderID` and `OrderDate` in select **?** This is an example from a website, and does not explain this. I am not sure if it has to do with join (which is in the example) so that's why I also put it there and in the tags.

-Thanks

Comment: You specify the table (directly or by its alias, I would encourage the use of aliases pretty much all the time), so sql server knows where to find the column. It's not necessary if the column name is unique (for example if `OrderID` doesn't exist in `Customers`). Even if it's not necessary its always advisable to use, so you (and the people who have to maintain your code) can also easily tell which column comes from which table. especially when you start joining multiple tables.

Comment: @HoneyBadger So it's required if other data tables have the same column name? CustomerName is unique and OrderDate. Additionally, if it is "FROM Orders", then why is querying other tables? Why bother have the From at all if you can just use the dot operator...

Comment: This is how sql works. I don't think there is much use in asking why it works this way.

Comment: @HoneyBadger so can it say FROM Customers and this will still work the same?

Comment: It's exactly the same as `object.property`  If you don't specify which table the column is to be read from, the SQL engine has to infer it, and if both tables have columns with the same name, it can't tell which one you mean.  Worse still, when a colleague comes to read your code, they have to Guess.  You should join an obfuscated coding competition if you really want your code to be hard to read.

Comment: Yes, in this case the two tables can be switched around. But not if you'd need an outer join (left or right).

Comment: @HoneyBadger last question. if it is `SELECT <table_name>.<category_in_table_name>, <table_name2>.<dategory2_in_table_name>, ...` then FROM can be `FROM <AnyTableNameInDatabase>`?

Comment: This has obviously got to be a faq. (Not that there is actually a clear statement of your question in your post.) Googling 'site:stackoverflow.com sql why qualify a column name when not necessary'. See the close-vote link for one of many duplicates. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS That duplicate link is *ten years old*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I Always Fully Qualify Column Names In SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557240/should-i-always-fully-qualify-column-names-in-sql)

Comment: You are jumping to (wrong) conclusions.

Comment: @philipxy then one would clarify, not assume I am asking a different question than what was **explicitly** stated.

Comment: Again, you are jumping to (wrong) conclusions.

Comment: @philipxy then as I have again **explicitly** stated before, clarify what "wrong" conclusion I jumped to.

Comment: What do you think you explicitly stated? Whatever you're trying to say about that, you are not using enough words to be clear. The jumps to conclusions are that I am bored or am assuming anything.

Comment: @philipxy then  why do you think I am asking a different question than the question I explcitily asked, "If it is from the Orders table, why specify Orders. before the OrderID and OrderDate in select" That is the question.  And then I quote you: "Not that there is actually a clear statement of your question in your post."

Comment: You keep giving (wrong) justifications for jumping to conclusions. Another original jump was that I didn't carefully read your question. I'm done.

Comment: @philipxy so you admit it's a question. Ciao.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the column name is found in both tables and your DBMS will throw an error that the column is ambiguous.  It's usually a good idea to explicitly declare which table you want the item to come from.

Using an alias often make the code easier to read and write:

```
SELECT ord.OrderID, cus.CustomerName, ord.OrderDate
FROM Orders ord
INNER JOIN Customers cus ON ord.CustomerID=cus.CustomerID;
```

These table names are pretty short, but you can see how useful aliases can be when the table names become longer and more complicated.

One benefit to explicitly declaring the table is that you can tell at a glance what table the data is coming from.  Once you have data coming from many sources, through joins or not, it can be difficult to tell exactly which table a field is coming from, if you do not show the table in the select statements.

Comment: So the word before the dot is just an Aliase? I thought you use AS for aliases.

Comment: Yes, you can see that "ord" also follows Orders in the FROM section.  That is where you are telling the DBMS that ord is an alias for Orders.  Same goes for "cus" following INNER JOIN Customers.  Using AS is optional in this case.

Comment: @JustAFellowCoder - `AS ord` ***defines*** the alias.  `ord.CustomerID` is reading the column `CustomerID` from the table referenced by the alias `ord`.

Comment: @JustAFellowCoder - Read my comment on your post, and read some tutorials.  I'm sorry, but you're now headed down the route of `please teach me SQL's syntax` rather than asking a specific question.

Comment: @MatBailie Fair. I'll go do that. The original question was answered, so thanks all of y'all :). Happy coding.